# How to control Enttec Open DMX USB via Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, libusb, dmx512

I'm wondering is that possible to control lights connected to Enttec Open DMX USB via Python shell. If it is, how to?

Comment: Do you mean something like the [C# example](http://www.enttec.com/download/examples/OpenDMX.cs) linked on the [product page](http://www.enttec.com/?main_menu=Products&pn=70303)? Seems like it wouldn't be too hard using ctypes to access the ftd2xx library. I'm not sure about the DMX512 timing. Looks like they just have a 20ms sleep in `writeData`.

Comment: Yes, something like you linked is what I mean. I'm not PRO with Python, so can you tell what I shold to do to get started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Open Lighting Project](https://www.openlighting.org/) (formerly known as [opendmx](http://www.opendmx.net)) provides a [Python API](http://www.openlighting.org/ola/developer-documentation/python-api/), as part of their Open Lighting Architecture (OLA), for use the OpenDMX USB on OSX and Linux. If you're on Windows then I've not found anything apart from the code from Enttec's website which uses the FTD2XX.DLL libraries.

However it should be noted that one cannot use normal serial based libraries (pyserial etc). Basically OLA either needs to use a special kernel module on Linux, or use the generic FTDI non-serial kernel driver in combination with libftdi on Mac or Linux - for details see their [device specific page](http://www.openlighting.org/ola/getting-started/device-specific-configuration/#Open_DMX_USB_FTDI_RS485). There is now pre-built [support for Raspberry Pi's on the OLA website](https://www.openlighting.org/ola/tutorials/ola-on-raspberry-pi/).

The communication and protocols used are completely different from Enttec Pro range (which one can just control using simple serial commands with something like pyserial, though OLA also talks to them too).

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, so I wrote a simple python programm for all those that are running windows; have a look: https://github.com/Coronon/PyOpenDmxUsb

It uses a C# Server (Because their C# interface was the only one that worked for me) and a Python Client and is super easy to use.

It is **compatible with the non pro version** too. (The Pro Version is way easier to use and I would use the AcceptedAnswer instead [But the normal one isnt supported])

Edit: This may be 'advertisement' but my project is Open-Source and super easy to use, so I believe this can be useful to others :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old post, however [DmxPy](https://github.com/davepaul0/DmxPy) has worked very well for me the last few months. It only works for Python 2 but I know there's some Python 3 ports out there.

It's stupid simple to use. I personally use it in my companies quality control software. While it only work for DMX (not RDM) I think it's much easier to use than OLA's Python Wrapper. It works flawlessly with our ENTTEC as well!

UPDATE: Here's my Python 3 port: https://github.com/trevordavies095/DmxPy

Comment: This library is only "compatible with Enttec's DMXUSB Pro" type devices.

Answer (score 0):

ENTTEC Open DMX is a rather simple device, all one needs to do is open its serial port and then keep sending all 512 channels prepended by a break and 0 start byte, in a loop, with a slight pause in between sends. Here is the the class and a small piece of code launching it in a separate thread:

```
import sys, time
import pyftdi.serialext

class DmxPy:
    def __init__(self, serialPort):
        try:
            self.serial = pyftdi.serialext.serial_for_url(serialPort, baudrate=250000, stopbits=2)
        except:
            print("Error: could not open Serial Port")
            sys.exit(0)
        self.dmxData = [bytes([0])] * 513
        self.dmxData[0] = bytes([0])
        
    def setChannel(self, chan, intensity):
        if chan > 512: chan = 512
        if chan < 0: chan = 0
        if intensity > 255: intensity = 255
        if intensity < 0: intensity = 0
        self.dmxData[chan] = bytes([intensity])
        
        
    def blackout(self):
        for i in range(1, 512, 1):
            self.dmxData[i] = bytes([0])
        
    def render(self):
        sdata = b''.join(self.dmxData)
        self.serial.send_break(duration=0.001)
        self.serial.write(sdata)

    def display_universe(self):
        while True:
            self.render()
            time.sleep(0.005)

dmx = DmxPy('ftdi://ftdi:232:A10NHECY/1') # note device serial in the connect string
dmx_thread = threading.Thread(target=dmx.display_universe)
dmx_thread.start()

dmx.setChannel(5,128)
```